# Datatable: search only by the first column not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code, search, datatable

I can't get this search to filter only by the first column (Header1). Now it searches ok but in all columns. What am I doing wrong?

```
var dtTbl = $('#companiesTable').datatable({
    columnDefs: [
        {
            "searchable": true,
            "targets": [0]
        }, {
            "searchable": false,
            "targets": [1, 4]
        }
    ],
    columns: [
        { label: 'Header1', sort: true, fixed: true },
        { label: 'Header2', sort: true, fixed: true },
        { label: 'Header3', sort: true, fixed: true },
        { label: 'Header4', sort: false },
        { label: 'Actions', field: 'actions', fixed: true, sort: false }
    ],
    rows: rows_builder,
    initComplete: function (settings, json) {
        alert('DataTables has finished its initialisation.');
    }
}, {

    pagination: false,
    striped: true,
    borderless: true,
    sm: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    hover: true,
    clickableRows: false,
    borderColor: "secondary",
    loaderClass: "bg-info",
    maxWidth: "100%",
    initComplete: function (settings, json) {
        alert('DataTables has finished its initialisation.');
    }
});

const customDatatable = document.getElementById('companiesTable');
const setActions = () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            $('.loading_spinner').show();
            $('.bodycontainer').empty();
            $('.bodycontainer').load('projects.html', function () {
                $('.loading_spinner').hide();
            });
        });
    })

    document.getElementsByClassName('delete_comp').forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            var idComp = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.id.split("_")[1]);
            Swal.fire({
                //deleted contents in order to shorten the length of the code
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    deleteCompany(idComp).done(function (res) {

                        if (res) {
                            Swal.fire({
                                //deleted contents in order to shorten the length of the code
                            }).then((result) => {
                                if (result.value) {
                                    //deleted contents in order to shorten the length of the code
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).fail(function (res) {
                       
                        Swal.fire(
                            //deleted contents in order to shorten the length of the code
                        );
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    })
}

customDatatable.addEventListener('render.mdb.datatable', setActions);

var instance = new mdb.Datatable(customDatatable, dtTbl);

document.getElementById('datatable-search-input').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    instance.search(e.target.value);
});
```

Also, I'm trying to debug "instance" but I can't get launch.json from my Visual Studio Code (1.6) to work, I get "unbound points". This is my configuration:

```
{
            "name": "Debug JAVASCRIPT chrome",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:8888/folder1/folder2/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}\folder2"
          
 
}
```

Thanks for your help!